# How to show this check box in all items of RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I wanna show all check box in all item of recycler view . when i long click on them.
I will show you what i want to do in this image.

[image]

[image]

When i long click on the picture folder in other  folders a empty check box will appear then we can choose them and do what we want to them. at the end how can i do this when i click on item and this happen.

this my adapter .

```
public class NoteAdapter extends Adapter<NoteAdapter.MyView> {
List<Note> notes;
Activity activity1;


public NoteAdapter(List<Note> noteList, Activity activity) {
    activity1 = activity;
    notes = noteList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NoteAdapter.MyView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_note, parent, false);
    return new MyView(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NoteAdapter.MyView holder, final int position) {
    holder.note.setText(notes.get(position).note);
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //the code at the line up just set visible the selected item but i want to set visible all items check boxs
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notes.size();
}

public class MyView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView name;
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    public MyView(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        note = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note);
        chackbox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chackBox);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add the images to your question not as link, also add the adapter code.

Comment: Just add onLongClick in your adapter!

Comment: i know that  how to add onLongClick but i cant set visible all checkbox to all items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public class NoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.MyView> {
List< Note > notes;
Activity activity1;
ArrayList<Integer> checkedList = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView recyclerView;

//.....

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NoteAdapter.MyView holder, final int position) {
    holder.name.setText(notes.get(position).note);
    holder.checkBox.setVisibility(checkedList.size() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(checkedList.contains(position));

}

//......

public class MyView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView name;
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    public MyView(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if(checkedList.contains(getAdapterPosition())){
                    checkedList.remove(Integer.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()));
                    if (checkedList.size() == 0){
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }else {
                        notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }else {
                    checkedList.add(getAdapterPosition());
                    if (checkedList.size() == 1){
                        recyclerView.post(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    }else {
                        notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                    }

                }
                //the code at the line up just set visible the selected item but i want to set visible all items check boxs
                return false;
            }
        });
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    if(!checkedList.contains(getAdapterPosition()))
                        checkedList.add(getAdapterPosition());
                }else{
                    checkedList.remove(Integer.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()));
                    if (checkedList.size() == 0){
                        recyclerView.post(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

I added long click method in the MyView and I made some changes. It works more stable. There is a position error in the **onBind** method.

**onAttachedToRecyclerView** : some times **notifyDataSetChanged()** method gives error. I added to be able to use recyclerView

Comment: thank you at first allVisible =  !allvisible ; then i want to checked the checkbox at that position i long click but whit this work i just make them visible.

Comment: see the second image i send when i long click on the picture folder all checkboxes become visible and the picture check box checked too.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can do it like that.

Comment: yeah it didn't work I tested it now when I long click on the third item they all become visible and first item will check. when i long click on sixth item the item at the fourth position will checked i don't know why this happen.

Comment: I tried a different way. Can you try this? In this way, you have the checkbox list selected.

Comment: it didn't visible all ????

Comment: can you test ur code in ur adapter ??? and see whats problem

Comment: You can try this. I tried my code and I fixed it.

Comment: that's not actually same as file Manger it has some problems but thank you a lot its too good.

Comment: Happy coding. You can improve the answer as you wish.